# Can I filter by values set with jQuery.data

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute, jquery-filter

I want to use a `.filter` function against a large number of elements where I'm checking for a `data-*` attribute, however they are set by the `.data` method.

The problem is that the jQuery selector always to use the original value. If I set a data value using `$('whatever').data('key', newValue)` and then try to use a selector `$('[data-key=newValue]')` then nothing is found.

Here's my test HTML:

```
<div id="test" data-dummy="foo"></div>
<div id="result"</div>
```

Then:

```
$('#test').data('dummy', 'bar');

$('#result').
    append('<div>Where dummy=foo: ' + $('[data-dummy="foo"]').length + '</div>').
    append('<div>Where dummy=bar: ' + $('[data-dummy="bar"]').length + '</div>');
```

Outputs:

> Where dummy=foo :1
>
> Where dummy=bar :0

It looks like, for the selector engine, only the original value is used in selectors.

**Update** - cheers to initial answers, this is actually on purpose. `.data` starts with `data-*` values, but sets its own copy. I don't want to replace every call to `.data(` with a call to `.attr('data-' +` .

To work around this I'm using `.filter` with a function, but as this filter will run for large numbers of elements I don't want to create a new jQuery object for each match. For this sort of circumstance jQuery provides some global functions.

Basically I should be able to use `$.data(element,` instead of `$(element).data(`, but this doesn't work either: `$.data(element,` returns `undefined`.

So my code ends up something like `.filter(function(){return $.data(this, key) === value;})`

However that appears to only be before a jQuery object is initialised:

```
var domEle = document.getElementById('test');
var globalBefore = $.data(domEle, 'dummy');
var first = $(domEle).data('dummy');
var globalAfter = $.data(domEle, 'dummy');

$('#result').
    append('<div>$.data before: ' + globalBefore + '</div>').
    append('<div>new $(): ' + first + '</div>').
    append('<div>$.data after: ' + globalAfter + '</div>');
```

Outputs:

> $.data before: undefined
>
> new $(): foo
>
> $.data after: foo

Weird. Never mind, the question is *can I work around it?* Is there any way to initialise whatever's happening for a new `$` object without creating one for every tested node?

JS Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kU4th/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bug, it's just really confusingly-designed behavior.

> The problem is that the jQuery selector seems to use the original value. If I set a data value using $('whatever').data('key', newValue) and then try to use a selector $('[data-key=newValue]') then nothing is found.

That's because `data` never *sets* `data-*` attributes, it just initializes itself from them. It's assymetrical (reads from them but doesn't write to them).

To actually update the attribute, use `attr`. E.g., instead of:

```
$('whatever').data('key', newValue);
```

you need

```
$('whatever').attr('data-key', newValue);
```

If you want to *both* set the data *and* the attribute:

```
$('whatever').data('key', newValue).attr('data-key', newValue);
```

`data` associates key/value pairs of data with elements using a jQuery-managed cache of objects. If you ask `data` for a key that doesn't already exist in the element's data cache, it looks to see if that key matches a `data-*` attribute and, if so, initializes the data cache with that value. At that point, there is **no** further connection between `data` and the `data-*` attribute.

The reason `data` doesn't write back to the attributes is probably at least partially down to the fact that you can store *anything* via `data`, whereas of course attribute values are always strings. So for instance, if you do:

```
$("whatever").data('key', {
    nice:   "complex",
    obj:    "here",
    answer: 42,
    when:   new Date()
});
```

...then later `$("whatever").data('key')` will give you back that object. That object cannot be stored in an attribute.

You're not, by far, the first person to be burned by this surprising design. :-)

---

> Basically I should be able to use `$.data(element`, instead of `$(element).data(`, but this doesn't work either: `$.data(element`, returns `undefined`.

Right. The [documentation for `$.data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) tells you why:

> **Note:** This is a low-level method; a more convenient `.data()` is also available.
>
> **Regarding HTML5 data-* attributes**: This low-level method does NOT retrieve the data-* attributes unless the more convenient `.data()` method has already retrieved them.

You've said you don't want to replace calls to `data` with calls to `attr`, but I have to say that seems like the best situation, so you can actually use those `data-*` attributes in selectors.

Alternately, you can do this:

```
matchingElements.filter(function(){
    return ($.data(this, key) || this.getAttribute('data-' + key)) === value;
});
```

...which first looks at the `data` data and, if it gets back a falsey value (`undefined`, `null`, `""`, `false`, `NaN`, or `0`), goes and gets the attribute from the element instead. If you want to limit that to just `undefined`:

```
matchingElements.filter(function(){
    var value = $.data(this, key);
    return typeof value === "undefined" ? this.getAttribute('data-' + key) : value;
});
```

Comment: Cheers, that's a nice description of why I'm seeing the initial problem (i.e. design, not a bug) but unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem - I want to `.filter` elements by their `.data` values - why can't I use the global `$.data` here?

Comment: @Keith: I *thought* it answered the question: Use `attr`, and then the selectors will work. Those are basically your choices: Use `attr` to actually write attributes so the selectors can find them, or use `filter` and `data`. You said you didn't want to use `filter` because of the numbers involved, so that pretty much leaves `attr`. :-) (Also: Note that `$.data(element, key, value)` is just a different way to use `$(element).data(key, value)`, except the global version doesn't go and check `data-*` attrs if they haven't *already* been grabbed previously by the instance version.)

Comment: @Keith: I've added a bit to try to help further.

Answer (score 1):

jquery's data method and the HTML5 data-* attributes are completely different animals.

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/):

> Regarding HTML5 data-* attributes: This low-level method does NOT retrieve the data-* attributes unless the more convenient .data() method has already retrieved them.

What you set through

```
$(selector).data('key', value)
```

you retrieve through

```
var foo = $(selector).data('key')
```

If you want to use html data-* attributes, use

```
$(selector).attr('data-key', value)
```

and retrieve it with

```
var foo = $(selector).attr('data-key');
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery reads data attributes, but then the data is stored separately from the attributes. Setting data on an element doesn't affect the attributes.

If you want the attributes to be changed also, you need to use the `attr` method to set the value instead of the `data` method:

```
$('#test').attr('data-dummy', 'bar');
```

This will set both the `data-dummy` attribute on the element, and the value of `data('dummy')` for the element.